# Unable to run a batch update of contribution soft credits

Tags: profile, contributions, upgrade

I created a profile with only two fields:
Soft Credit
Soft Credit Type

I intend to use it to go back into my contributions and assign soft credits to contributions.

First I go to Contributions -> Find Contributions and execute my search.  I select 'Update Multiple Contributions', and I select my Soft Credit profile.

The relevant contributions are displayed.  But the Soft Credit and Soft Credit Type fields are blocked/blank.  I know some of my contributions already have soft credits assigned but that information doesn't show.  And I am not able to assign new soft credits to any contributions.

I thought this functionality was added in 2013: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Soft+Credit+Enhancements+-+4.4

I have no trouble updating contributions' Thank You dates with another profile.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Currently updating contribution to add/update soft credits are not supported. I feel Updating soft credit was missed during initial implementation. We will need to submit a core fix to have it working for Contribution Batch update.

Comment: We really need this functionality. How do we "submit a core fix" and/or is this a huge task? Could we pay to escalate it? thanks

Comment: Would you like to email me at pradpnayak at Gmail dot com? Or you can log an issue  in civicrm git lab under paid issues